# Need to find positing of index location of a word from a sentence inputted by a user

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, input, indexing

Write a program that prompts the user to enter two inputs: some text and a word.
The program outputs the starting indices of all occurrences of the word in the text.
If the word is not found, the program should output “not found”

```
phrase = input('Enter a Sentence: ')
print(phrase)
phrase1 = input('Enter a word from the sentence: ')
words = (phrase.split())
if phrase1 in words:
    for w in range(len(words)):
        if words[w] == phrase1:
            print(words.index(phrase1))

else:
    print("Not found.")
```

This is what I have. I have the users input, the output not found, however, finding each index to the second input is not doing what I want it to do. below is the example of what it should look like. Any help would be appreciated with comments that help explain it. Thanks.
Example 1:

```
Input1: 'my dog and myself are going to my friend'
Input2: 'my'
Output: 0 11 31
```

Example 2:

```
Input1: 'Programming is fun'
Input2: 'my'
Output: 'not found'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not do `words.index(...)` as this will return the index in the `words` rather than the `phrase`.

Here is an alternative implementation:

```
phrase = input('Enter a Sentence: ')
print(phrase)

word = input('Enter a word from the sentence: ')
offset = -1

if word in phrase:
    while word in phrase[offset+1:]:
        offset = phrase.index(word, offset+1)
        print(offset)
else:
    print('Not found.')
```